# Angular 7: ngOnChanges fires only once

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I can't figure out why **`ngOnChanges`** only fires once. When initially set.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-fixed-decimals-input',
    templateUrl: './fixed-decimals-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./fixed-decimals-input.component.scss'],
})
export class FixedDecimalsInputComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() value: number;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
    }
}


// html file
    <input name="value" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

changes to value do not trigger **`ngOnChanges`**
any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`ngOnChanges` only gets triggered when the `@Input()` gets changed from the parent component, not if you change it in you child component.

Comment: well isn't that exactly the purpose of 2 way binding?

Comment: Yeah figured that out, but then what does get fired when you change it in your child component?